# renderHighchart inside module using reactive dataset

Tags: r, shiny, r-highcharter

I am trying to create a Shiny App based on modules and I need to add a `highchart` inside a module where the graph updates when the user selects a value from a `selectInput` dropdown. The idea is that when the user select a value from a `selectInput` box in the UI, this filters a dataset and then the `highchart` is updated.  The problem is that I am not able to pass the filtered dataset to the `myModuleServer` (see below). How can I do this?

This is the dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(label = c('A','B'), value = c(10,25))
```

These are the modules UI and Server:

```
myModuleUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    textOutput(ns("title")),
    textOutput(ns("text")),
    highchartOutput(ns("graph")))}

myModuleServer <- function(input, output, session, action, dataset) {  
  output$title <- renderText({paste0("You selected letter: ",action())})
  output$text <- renderText({paste0("In the dataset the letter selected corresponds to number: ", dataset()$value)})
  output$graph <- renderHighchart({hchart(dataset(), 'bar', hcaes(x=dataset()$label, y=dataset()$value))})
  }
```

Below both the UI and Server components of a Shiny App:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 3, wellPanel(selectInput('dummy', 'Select a letter', choices = c('A', 'B')))),
    column(width = 6, myModuleUI("module1")))
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  reactiveData <- reactive({input$dummy})
  reactiveDataSet <- reactive({df %>% filter(label == input$dummy)})

  callModule(myModuleServer, 'module1', action = reactiveData, dataset = reactiveDataSet)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Use `hchart(dataset(), 'bar', hcaes(x=label, y=value))`. Inside `hcaes` you should specify the column names rather than `datasetname()$columnname`.

Comment: Thanks GyD. That solved the problem!